# Ошибка при создании связанных таблиц

Tags: postgresql

Есть 2 таблицы:

Поле `code_comment` таблицы `files_comments` ссылается на `code_comment` таблицы `comments`.

Но при выполнении данного кода возникает ошибка:

```
ERROR:  there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table "files_comments"
```

Как исправить?

```
--create table with comments.
create table if not exists comments(
    code_comment serial PRIMARY KEY not null references files_comments(code_comment),
    code_task integer,
    body_comment text,
    create_time timestamp,
    user_id integer
);


--create table with files of comments paths.
create table if not exists files_comments(
    file_id serial PRIMARY KEY,
    file_path text NOT NULL,
    code_comment integer
);
```

Comment: Как и в предыдущем вашем вопросе, все наоборот должно быть.

Comment: Ссылаться должен не первичный ключ. Ссылка из подчиненной таблицы должна указывать на первичный ключ другой таблицы

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FOREIGN KEY организует ссылочную целостность для связи один-ко-много (реже один-к-один). При этом на стороне "один" создаётся уникальный (обычно - это первичный) индекс, а на стороне "много" - внешний ключ (FK) на этот индекс. Т.е.

```
--create table with comments.
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS comments(
    code_comment SERIAL NOT NULL,
    code_task INTEGER,
    body_comment TEXT,
    create_time TIMESTAMP,
    user_id INTEGER,
    PRIMARY KEY (code_comment)
);

--create table with file' paths of comments.
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS files_comments(
    file_id SERIAL NOT NULL,
    file_path TEXT NOT NULL,
    code_comment INTEGER NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (file_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (code_comment) REFERENCES comments(code_comment)
);
```

Т.е.

```
FOREIGN KEY (поля_этой_таблицы)
    REFERENCES другая_таблица (поля_другой_таблицы_как_в_уникальном_индексе)
```

Comment: а кл. сл. `FOREIGN KEY` обязательно? это может быть записано как `code_comment integer not null references comments(code_comment)`?

Comment: вот у меня аналогичный случай я вроде все сделал: create table if not exists privilege_roles(
    role char(10) PRIMARY KEY,
    data_view boolean,
    data_injection boolean
); и create table if not exists users(
    user_id serial PRIMARY KEY,
    username char(20),
    password char(20),
    email char(30),
    FOREIGN KEY (role) references privilege_roles(role)
); пишет ERROR:  column "role" referenced in foreign key constraint does not exist

Comment: 1) Можно, но с FK нагляднее. 2) В таблице users нет поля role, о чём и сообщается.

Comment: все у меня все получилось я понял спасибо!